# Ecommerce with django in google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, e-commerce

Is there any module available for googlecheckout/paypal in django on google app engine? are there any example apps which are doing this?

Comment: There's http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal, though I'm not sure if that works with GAE.

Answer (score 3):

Example for using Paypal with django: http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/11/using-paypal-with-django/

The same concept is expanded into a generic snippet: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1181/

And that is made into a pluggable paypal app: http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal/tree/master